# Can I limit my SSH Tunneling Speed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bandwidth, ssh-tunnel

So, I'm using my ssh tunneling to download some content which is blocked by my office. But, I don't want the admin to notice it, therefore I want to limit the connection to, eg: 20KB/s.

How can I do that? 
FYI: 
-I'm using DownThemAll to download the content.
-I'm using ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DownThemAll, but I see that it's a Firefox extension. So you could try running [trickle](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/trickle) to launch Firefox with a download limit (see [man trickle](http://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle)). For example:

```
trickle -d 20 firefox
```

That will set a download limit of 20 KB/s.

For completeness, users running Windows can do the same by using the [Firefox Throttle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917) add-on.

Comment: ah yes, just limit the bandwitdh the firefox uses, briliant! Thank you,

Comment: Don't mention it. And welcome to Server Fault!

Answer (score 0):

QoS and bandwidth management for Linux.

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html

But you probably just want to forget about it.

edit: not because it's technically difficult, but because it sounds like a good way to get yourself in trouble.

Comment: mfriedman - trickle is seriously cool.  ive never seen that before.  (seems i can only comment on my own posts though...)